# Normalize matrix l2 norm

Tags: math, svd

Normalize matrix A to get matrix B, where each column vector of B has unit L2-norm.

I don't know what this means. Do I do this?

Take sum of col and sqrt.

```
[1 0       
 1 1]  --> [1.4 1]
```

or
Make each column have l2-norm of 1.

```
[1 0       
 1 1]   
--v         
[0.7 0   
0.7 1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning is that you should replace each column vector with its corresponding normalized [versor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versor_(physics)).

For example (Python)

```
m = [[1, 0],
     [1, 1]]

rows, cols = len(m), len(m[0])
for col in range(cols):
    length = sum(m[row][col]**2 for row in range(rows)) ** 0.5
    for row in range(rows):
        m[row][col] /= length
```

changes `m` to

```
[[0.7071067811865475, 0.0],
 [0.7071067811865475, 1.0]]
```